# Does the terminal driver buffer store the characters a user types? If so, how can one access those?

Tags: c, terminal, buffer

I'm writing a multi-threaded chat program in C, and if I'm typing in something and at the same time receive any message, it puts this message in front of what I was typing, messing up with my input. So yeah, is there any way to access the characters a user has just typed in if he hasn't pressed enter yet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. If you put the terminal into raw mode, you'll get everything directly, instead of line-by-line processed by the terminal driver. However, if you're going to go that route, you're much better off learning how to use Curses or some similar terminal control library, rather than trying to manage the terminal directly.